# Connecting two displays using CalDigit hub makes 16" Mac unresponsive

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I have the CalDigit USB-C Pro dock which has two 1080p displays, keyboard and mouse connected to it.
To power it, I have been using my 16" MacBook Pro.

This configuration has been working great until it updated to Big Sur. Now, when I connect my Mac to the dock, all screens turn black and the MacBook is unresponsive unless I unplug the dock.

I thought it could be software/driver issue so I factory reset my Mac and tried the dock… which to my surprise did not work! I have also cleared NVRAM which did not help.

My old 2017 15" Mac Pro **does** work with this dock even with Big Sur! So my thinking is that is has got to be an issue with my 16" Mac

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you contacted CalDigit support to report the problem? Perhaps they are aware of the issue and either have a solution or are working on the problem.

Comment: No, I have not, but I will do it now. I thought that there would be no point as my older mac works with the dock.